# Rails 5. Track the order of Associations between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I can think of ways to implement this myself however, I'm hoping someone can link to a gem or perhaps just an applicable sorting algorithim in ruby.

**Problem**

Track the order of associations between two models. Allowing the user to, using the example models below, both create `children` that `belong_to` a `parent` and order them by most favourite to least favourite.

To be clear I *don't* mean order an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or add an order by clause to an sql statement.

I'd like the user to be able to CRUD `children`, and CRUD their order in the same form (as they order will likely be stored in the same model)

I was considering using the `favourite_order` column (see the schema below) to track the order however, if child 4 was promoted to 1st (ate a bear, levelled up) the rest would bubble down accordingly i.e. 1st would become 2nd etc. Another exmaple, is the 2nd child is deleted (died in a forest fire) , all children of a lower rank would automatically be promoted i.e. their ranks would increase by one.

Know of any gems that provide this feature or any sorting algorithms I could use to implement it myself?

**Example**

*app/models/parent.rb*

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
end
```

*app/models/child.rb*

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

*db/schema.rb*

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170812100949) do

  create_table "children", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "parent_id"
    t.text "child_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end  

  create_table "parents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "parent_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

Comment: does a parent and/or child belongs to a specific user? I want to know if `Parent A` and its `Children` should be ordered differently for each `User` or if there is only one valid order for `Parent A` and its `Children`

Comment: No sir, the only models involved are `child` and `parent`. By user, I mean't the human using the software.

Comment: So you can confirm that there is only one true order between a Parent and its children, right?

Comment: Yes. However, I have found the information I need in Leito's answer. Thanks  for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that bubbling that you mention there are gems like [ranked-model](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model) and [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) that would handle that for you. Usually they have a underlaying `x_position` field, that you don't write directly, so the gems handle the updates for you. You simply add to the end, to the beginning or at a specific position in the "list".